# PHP & Javascript: Image file description properties (Summary tab)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, file

Image files come with description properties like title, subject and keyword (summary tab). How do I "get" these properties in PHP? is there a function that allows me to the same in Javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `exif_read_data()` function within PHP.

Here is the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php), and here's [an example of it in use](http://www.v-nessa.net/2010/08/02/using-php-to-extract-image-exif-data).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding JavaScript, there is [a script](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/) that will allow you to read EXIF information. It uses a rather complex technique using XMLHttpRequest.

Another technique (in its infancy) is to read the file on the client side, using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) interface. An example of using FileReader to read EXIF data was posted on a [Mozilla Hacks blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/firefox-36-fileapi-demo-reading-exif-data-from-a-local-jpeg-file/).

I know you didn't mention EXIF at all and you want to access those Windows file properties. Honestly, I don't know how you'd acess those. You'd probably have to read certain bytes in the file, just like the script at the EXIF example from Mozilla Hacks does.