# How to read description of image file using php

Tags: php, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting exif data from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319803/getting-exif-data-from-php)

I am making a gallery from images in a folder using the following code:

```
<div id="gallery"><ul>
<?php
foreach (glob("gallery/*") as $filename) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$filename.'" title="">';
    echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" alt="" /></a></li>';
}
?>
</ul></div>
```

In the title filed of a tag I want to print a description from the image file properties. Is there any way?

i made some changes to this code using getimagedata() function...

```
<div id="gallery"><ul>  <?php
foreach (glob("gallery/*.jpg") as $filename) {
$size = getimagesize($filename, $info);
    echo '<li><a href="'.$filename.'" title="'; 
    var_dump($info['APP0']);
    echo '"><img src="'.$filename.'" alt="" /></a></li>';
}
?></ul></div>
```

but it gives unreadable output. like this string 'JFIF���d�d��' *(length=14)*

and also i used exif_read_data() function it show call to undefined function error....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005476/php-javascript-image-file-description-properties-summary-tab

Comment: On your database you store paths of pictures , store also a brief description, query it and echo it out on the title

Comment: i modified my code using getimagedata() function    please look code above

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but [`exif_read_data()`](http://php.net/exif-read-data) should do the job.

Comment: hey thanks for answer but it not working on my hosting server.... does it requires any additional package.... it says call to undefined function..... i think it will work

Comment: This feature must be enabled when compile php. check `phpinfo()` for `--enable-exif`. But since its not an `undefinied function`, it will not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on *where*  the metadata are stored (and of course also on the format of the files: not all image formats allow metadata). Beyond EXIF, you could be interested also in reading about [iptcparse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php). For example images created or manipulated with Adobe PhotoShop could have some metadata you could be interested in as IPTC metadata. See also the [IPTC Photo Metadata Standard](http://www.iptc.org/site/Home/).